# Seat issues in weird Air France booking

Tags: bookings, check-in, seating, air-france

I booked my Air France flight a few months ago and am having issues.

On the app it says my boarding passes are unavailable and have to print them at the check-in counter.

On the seat section it says:

> We're sorry, we cannot confirm the seat you booked. Please make a note of your new seat number.

And on the documents section, it says:

> "One of your flights has been modified. We're sorry, the seat you booked is no longer available.
>   Please see the Seats section of this page.

Is this normal?

Comment: It's not unusual in my experience.

Comment: @phoog i've never had this before, quite scared about it

Comment: I suppose they had to substitute a different aircraft. If I were in your shoes I'd arrive at the airport as early as possible since the new plane might be smaller.

Comment: @phoog the flights already at 6am...

Comment: Well depending on the circumstances I might consider going the b night before.  Or if I were flexible about the possibility of delay, I'd just show up at the normal time and prepare to be denied boarding and compensated appropriately.

Comment: @Daniil Have you tried the old-fashioned approach of speaking to AF customer services?

Comment: @Traveller I thought about mentioning that, but in my experience that's not usually helpful.  On the other hand, my experiences are probably not directly relevant because they usually concern different reasons for being unable to check in, namely limitations based on immigration status or online check in not being supported at the departure airport.  I suppose customer service may at least be able to shed some light on the change or on other reasons underlying the situation.

Comment: And sometime the English in AirFrance app/website is ...very French, especially on error messages, or special cases. [You may get better and preciser message in French]

Comment: This happened to us on a cross-Atlantic flight this summer.  The new seats they gave us were basically the exact same seats we'd already had.  I gather they were just on a different plane.  It caused no problems whatsoever and seemed a bit silly to notify us about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a phone call with customer services they explained that they were having a technical fault, therefore the boarding passes couldn’t be accessed and the seats couldn’t be confirmed.

It turns out it was indeed an aircraft change and the new aircraft had more seats than the old one.